# Adding days on top of another calucated date

Tags: php, date

I am calculating a tentative due date for each task within a project, and I calculated the first task's due date just fine, which was 5 business days from the project start date, but now I want to calculate each new based off of the previous tasks's due date.

The project Start date is 7-15-13
Task one has a duration of 5 days, which should set deadline date to 7-22-13
Task two has a duration of 5 days, which should set deadline date to 7-19-13
Task three has a duration of 3 days which should set my deadline date to 7-24-13.

Each project can have a variable number of tasks.

```
        //Format the Start Date
    $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($projectStart));

    //Subtract one day to project length to include the starting date in the count.
    $projectLengthMinusOne = ($projectLength - 1);

    //Calculate estimated deadline date based off of out of office, absence, holidays, and weekdays.
    $deadlineDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($projectLengthMinusOne . ' weekdays', strtotime($startDate)));

    //Check for holidays
    $checkHolidays = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM fm_calendar_holidays WHERE fromDate BETWEEN '".$startDate."' AND '".$deadlineDate."'") or die("Check Holidays: " . mysql_error());
    $numHolidays = mysql_num_rows($checkHolidays);

    //Check for Absences
    $checkAbsences = mysql_query("SELECT numDays FROM fm_calendar_absenceRequest WHERE startDate BETWEEN '".$startDate."' AND '".$deadlineDate."' and respid = '".$taskData['assignedTo']."'") or die("Check Absences: " . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkAbsences) > 0)
        {
        $totalAbsences = 0;

        while($abData = mysql_fetch_array($checkAbsences))
            {
            $numDays = $abData['numDays'];
            $totalAbsences += $numDays;
            }
        }

    $numAbsences = $totalAbsences;

    //Check for out of office
    $checkOutOffice = mysql_query("SELECT startDate, endDate FROM fm_calendar_outofOffice WHERE startDate BETWEEN '".$startDate."' AND '".$deadlineDate."' and requesterId = '".$taskData['assignedTo']."'") or die("Check Out of Office: " . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkOutOffice) > 0)
        {
        $totalOutOffice = 0;

        while($oooData = mysql_fetch_array($checkOutOffice))
            {
            $oooStart = $oooData['startDate'];
            $oooEnd = $oooData['endDate'];

            $numWorkingDays = getWorkingDays($oooStart, $oooEnd);

            $totalOutOffice += $numWorkingDays;
            }
        }

    $numOutOffice = $totalOutOffice;

    //Add up all days off from the calendar
    $totalDaysAdded = ($numHolidays + $numAbsences + $numOutOffice);

    //Recalculate the deadline date based off of the new days off information
    $deadlineDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($totalDaysAdded . ' weekdays', strtotime($deadlineDate)));

    $deadlineDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($taskData['taskLength'] . ' weekdays', strtotime($deadlineDate)));


    echo '<div class="page_collapsible" id="body-section1">'.$taskData['taskName'] . '<span></span></div>';

    echo '<div class="container">
                <div class="collapseContainer">';

                echo '<table width = "900px" cellspacing = "5" cellpadding = "5" border = "0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "125px" align="right"><strong>Description:</strong></td>
                                <td width = "775px" align="left">'.$taskData['taskDescription'] . '</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "125px" align="right"><strong>Programmer:</strong></td>
                                <td width = "775px" align="left">'.getCkname($taskData['assignedTo']). '</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "125px" align="right"><strong>Task Status:</strong></td>
                                <td width = "775px" align="left">'.$taskData['taskStatus'] . '</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "125px" align="right"><strong>Task Duration:</strong></td>
                                <td width = "775px" align="left">'.$taskData['taskLength'] . ' days</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width = "125px" align="right"><strong>Tentative Due Date:</strong></td>
                                <td width = "775px" align="left">'.$deadlineDate . '</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add dates is using DateTime::add() or the date_add function, for how to use these functions, you can look at the PHP manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/function.date-add.php